# How to show closed port with firewall-cmd?

Tags: firewall

I block port--10000 as udp protocal.

```
firewall-cmd --remove-port=10000/udp  --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

`firewall-cmd  --list-ports` can list all opened ports.Is there a way to list all ports blocked with `firewall-cmd --remove-port`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't block ports with `--remove-port`, but you remove ports added to the [zone](https://firewalld.org/documentation/zone/options.html). It depends on the option `target` whether the packets **not** matching the rules will be accepted, rejected or dropped.

> ```
> target="ACCEPT|%%REJECT%%|DROP"
> ```
>
> Can be used to accept, reject or drop every packet that doesn’t match
>   any rule (port, service, etc.). The `ACCEPT` target is used in trusted
>   zone to accept every packet not matching any rule. The `%%REJECT%%`
>   target is used in block zone to reject (with default firewalld reject
>   type) every packet not matching any rule. The `DROP` target is used in
>   drop zone to drop every packet not matching any rule. If the target is
>   not specified, every packet not matching any rule will be rejected.

Therefore, ports added with `firewall-cmd --add-port` are listed with `--list-ports`, and can be removed with `--remove-port`. If the port is not added, it can't be removed. There's no such thing as listing the removed ports.

There's a reason why the manual pages are chapter 12 at the end of the [documentation](https://firewalld.org/documentation/). Before getting into individual command line options you should be familar with the general [concepts](https://firewalld.org/documentation/concepts.html) like the [zones](https://firewalld.org/documentation/zone/).